# How can I extract 2 or 4 digits using python library regex? Doing \d{2,4} also extracts substrings with 3 consecutive digits

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract years from a text. In this text years can appear as 2 or 4 digits.. Which regex expression should i use for this?

\d{2,4} also extracts substrings with 3 consecutive digits and that is not something I want.

Comment: You could use `\b\d\d(\d\d)?\b`, but your text might have 2-digit numbers which are not years.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the qualifier `{2,4}` allows for 3. Instead specify you want two digits which are optionally followed by 2 more. You also need to be sure there are no *more* digits adjacent to the match. For that you can use `\b`. So that gives:

```
\b\d\d(\d\d)?\b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search specifically for the two eligible lengths `\d{2}|\d{4}` with no other digits around using `\b`:

```
 \b(\d{2}|\d{4})\b
```

Answer (score -1):

use findall and \d{2,4} and look behind to find the year phrase or the /

```
def extract_year(text):
    """Extract year from text using regular expression"""
    pattern = "(?<=\d\/)\d{2,4}\s|(?<=\syear)\s+\d{2,4}" # regular expression pattern to look for
    result = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return result

# test cases
text1 = "The 10/24/1990  1/2/1992 Academy Awards, also called the Oscars, are a set of awards given annually for excellence of cinematic achievements. The awards, organized by the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences (AMPAS), were first handed out in 1929. At first, the Academy Awards ceremony was held in various locations such as a banquet hall of a hotel, until it finally settled at the Hollywood Roosevelt Hotel in the year 1929. The first Academy Awards ceremony consisted of a private dinner for 250 people in the Blossom Room of the Roosevelt Hotel, with an audience of five hundred people."
text2 = "The 10/24/91 Academy Awards, also called the Oscars, are a set of awards given annually for excellence of cinematic achievements. The awards, organized by the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences (AMPAS), were first handed out in 1929. At first, the Academy Awards ceremony was held in various locations such as a banquet hall of a hotel, until it finally settled at the Hollywood Roosevelt Hotel in the year 1929. The first Academy Awards ceremony consisted of a private dinner for 250 people in the Blossom Room of the Roosevelt Hotel, with an audience of five hundred people. Since then, the Academy Awards ceremonies take place every year except in the year 1943. That year, due to the World War II, the ceremony was not held. The Academy Awards ceremony is one of the oldest award ceremonies in the United States."

print(extract_year(text1))
print(extract_year(text2))
```

output:

```
['1990 ', '1992 ', '1929']
['91 ', '1929', '1943']
```